# NASM - Display value address

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

I have a table of 20 counts. How can I get a value "20" and display on console?

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
        mov     eax,4
        mov     ebx,1
        mov     ecx,length
        mov     edx,[length]

        mov     eax,1
        int     80h

section .data
variable times 20  db      0
length  dd $-variable
```

I thought about something like upper, but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Convert the number to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064565/a-should-be-simple-program-with-nasm-doesntt-work/25065047#25065047), then print the string.

Comment: OK, thank you man. I will use it.

Answer (score 0):

At least call the function prior to exiting!

```
mov     eax,4
mov     ebx,1
mov     ecx,length
mov     edx,[length]
int     80h    ; <== Forgotten
mov     eax,1
int     80h
```