# Printing current pid in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I need some machine code to give me the current pid. I got the following syscalls 4 = write and 20 = getpid , This is the code I used from another source.

```
SECTION .data

LookUpDig db "0123456789"             

PIDString db "PID: "
PIDLength equ $-PIDString

SECTION .bss

PID: resb 8                           

SECTION .text

global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 20                 
    int 0x80                       
    mov ebx, 0xA                   
    lea ebp, [PID+6]                  

ASCIIConv: 
    div ebx                           
    mov byte cl, [LookUpDig+edx]      
    mov [ebp], cl                   
    dec ebp                       
    xor edx, edx                   
    inc eax                        
    dec eax                         
    jnz ASCIIConv                    
    jz .printOut                  

.printOut:
    push PIDLength                  
    push PIDString                   
    push 0x1                      
    mov eax, 4                    
    push eax                        
    int 0x80                        
    add esp, 0x10                  
    
    mov [PID+7], byte 0xA            
    
    push 0x8                        
    push PID                     
    push 0x1                       
    mov eax, 4                     
    push eax                        
    int 0x80                      
    add esp, 0x10                    
    mov eax, 0x1                    
    push 0x0                      
    int 0x80
```

I use this to compile it:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o try.o try.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o try try.o
```

Where try is the asm file im working with.
The output I get is nothing and it return normally.

Thanks for any help! :)
NOTE: First time ever Ive dealt with Assembly

Comment: It's weird that you only zero EDX *after* `div`, not before.  It happens to work because Linux happens to zero the registers before entering user-space, and nothing else runs before _start since you linked it as a static executable.  It's also weird that you use a lookup table instead of `add dl, '0'` since the ASCII codes for the decimal digits are contiguous (unlike hex).  Your `push` instructions before the later `int 0x80` system calls are also weird. Like maybe you were copying from shellcode that used `push 4` / `pop eax` instead of `mov eax,4` (to avoid zeros in the machine code).

Comment: Anyway, run `strace ./try` and see what system calls your program makes, and single-step it with GDB to narrow down further.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some asm GDB tips at the bottom.

Comment: Looks like your attempt to print the string is just some random guesses without looking up the calling conventions.  (as well as a misunderstanding about assemble-time `equ` constants being assemble-time, not magically updating at run-time if you store bytes past the end of the space you reserved for the string.)  There are no comments to explain the intended purpose of the instructions.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) covers int -> string but the example uses a 64-bit `syscall`, which uses a different calling convention for the register args.  Still, it does show how to correctly get the pointer and length into registers.

Comment: Oh, you're not claiming to have written this.  *This is the code I used from another source*.  So the system-call part at the end might not be your nonsense, IDK.  [Add 2 numbers and print the result using Assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28524535) has a working 32-bit Linux int->string + `write`

Comment: Looked up with the strace ./try and I can see the problem is in the write section. It looks like this write(10, "", 0) ) = -1 EBADF

Comment: That would make sense; EBX is still `10` at that point, and you didn't put a pointer in ECX or a length in EDX.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter Cordes for such a fast answer! Finally solved it! Changed the push part:    push PIDLength ,                 
    push PIDString ,                  
    and push 0x1 to mov edx, 0x8, mov exc, pid and mov ebx ,1