# Decimal printing with NASM issue?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

NASM code:

```
section .text
        global _start


_start:
        mov eax,22


printDecimal:
        push eax
printDecimalSub:
        mov edx,0
        mov ecx,10
        div ecx

        push eax
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,edx
        add ecx,48
        mov edx,1
        int 80h
        pop eax

        cmp eax,0
        jne printDecimalSub

printBinary:

exit:
        mov eax,1
```

The code works but nothing is displayed on screen.
I don't understand where I made a mistake. I am on linux.

Comment: `write` wants a pointer to a char, not a character by value, even when EDX=1.  The canonical duplicate about this uses x86-64 with `syscall`, not 32-bit with `int 0x80`, but adapt as necessary or use the 32-bit code in [Add 2 numbers and print the result using Assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524951)

Comment: Once you make ECX point to the character (instead of being the character), you'll see that the number gets displayed in reverse! The value 123 appears on screen as "321".

Comment: @SepRoland I know. I wanted to test whether the code I have written so far is correct.

Comment: @suiciyom Well it isn't! Solve the issue that @PeterCordes told you about with 
 something like: `div ecx` `add edx, 48` `PUSH EDX` `MOV ECX, ESP` `push eax` `mov eax,4` `mov ebx,1` `mov edx,1` `int 80h` `pop eax` `POP EDX`