# What is limiting the size of variables / registers in assembly? (32-bit Linux)

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

EDIT: okay, there's the code:

```
global _start


section .text
_start:
    ; presetting variables
    mov [rev_ans], byte 0
    mov [multiplier], byte 1
    
    ; square of num
    mov eax,31
    mov ebx,eax
    mul ebx
    mov [left_num],eax
    
    ; know the digits count of the answer
    mov [digit_count_left_num],eax
    call digit_num
    
    ; convert into ascii digits and store one by one reversed
    call reverse_ans
    
    ; print
    mov eax, [rev_ans]
    mov [left_num], eax
    call print_ans

    ; exit
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
    
    
    
reverse_ans:
    ; restoring eax data
    mov eax,[left_num]
    mov edx,0
    mov ebx,10
    div ebx
    
    ; moving left number (undisplayed yet) into left_num
    mov [left_num],eax
    
    ; building reversed answer integer
    mov eax,[multiplier]
    mov ecx,edx
    mov edx,0
    mul ecx
    add [rev_ans],eax
    
    ; incrementing the multiplier
    mov eax,[multiplier]
    mov ebx,10
    mov edx,0
    div ebx
    mov [multiplier],eax    
    
    ; repeating process for other digits
    cmp [left_num], byte 0
    jg reverse_ans
    
    ret
    
    
    
    
print_ans:
    ; restoring eax data
    mov eax,[left_num]
    mov edx,0
    mov ebx,10
    div ebx
    mov [ans],edx
    
    ; converting into ascii digit
    add [ans], byte 0x30
    
    ; moving the number which is left (undisplayed yet) into left_num
    mov [left_num],eax
    
    ; print
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,ans
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    
    ; repeating process for other digits
    cmp [left_num], byte 0
    jg print_ans
    
    ret


digit_num:
    ; increment multiplier
    mov eax, [multiplier]
    mov ebx,10
    mov edx,0
    mul ebx
    mov [multiplier],eax
    
    ; check
    mov eax,[digit_count_left_num]
    mov ebx,[multiplier]
    mov edx,0
    div ebx
    ; updating the number which was left after division
    mov [digit_count_left_num],eax
    
    cmp eax, byte 0
    jg digit_num
    ret




section .bss
    ans resb 256
    digit resb 256
    left_num resb 256
    digit_count_left_num resb 256
    rev_ans resb 256
    multiplier resb 256
```

My program takes a hardcoded decimal number, squares it, and prints the answer on the screen. Everything works just fine if I give it a number, whose square is less than 1000. For example: I give it 2, it says 4;I give 31, it says 961. When I give it 32, it just prints 1 (where the answer should be 1024). When I input 65, the answer should be 4225, but appears as 0.
Also, I noticed a strange behavior: inputting 20 (and expecting 400) I get only 4.  Giving 10 also results in just 1 instead of 100. Giving 30 outputs 9.

A couple of things to mention:

1. While swapping the data between variables, at quite a few times I used general purpose registers (which are 32 bits in size) to temporarily store those variables' data. I thought that this could be an issue, but then I remembered that the maximum integer these registers can hold is over 4 billion! And my numbers are going just over a thousand!
2. All my variables in this program were reserved and not pre-initiated. For each variable I reserved 256 bytes in memory.

Comment: To answer the title, no, registers aren't limiting it. You have a logical problem somewhere corrupting the result.

Comment: It's difficult to debug code you've never seen.  Your problem is surely "you coded it wrong".  Any why on earth do you have 256-byte "variables"?

Comment: This is not the way to ask a question. We have no way to know what you've done wrong. If your code is too long to post, create a shorter example that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: So that they for sure wouldn't be limiting the values inside them.

Comment: You are asking how to debug this code.   You do it pretty much like any other language: run one line at a time in the debugger, called single stepping, and observe whether or not the program state is valid between each line as it is stopped before the next!  If you find a mismatch to your expectations, then investigate that.  Sometimes the issue occurs earlier in the program and you don't notice until later on, so then work backwards to debug earlier program flow to see why.

Comment: Converting a number to base-10 ASCII digits, in printing order (MSD-first) can and should be done with just one division inside a loop, not also multiplying anything by 10.  You also don't need to store/reload stuff in memory all the time; even 32-bit x86 has 7 registers other than the stack pointer.  That's not a lot, but it's enough for this.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) and [a 32-bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524951)

Comment: Also, to square EAX, just `mul eax` (or `imul eax,eax` if you don't want the high half of the result in EDX).  There's no need to involve EBX for that.  To multiply a register by 10, `imul reg, reg, 10`.  (Or like compilers do, `add ecx,ecx` / `lea ecx, [ecx+ecx*4]` to do x2 x5.)

Comment: `cmp [left_num], byte 0` is only checking the low byte of the result of `num /= 10;` and on half the values (signed `jg`) you stop looping.  A byte with its leading bit set can appear in the middle of any large number.  You wouldn't have this problem if you kept values in registers inside the loop.

Comment: Seems like all your "fail cases" have something in common: they all try to print a 0. None of the examples that worked correctly had a zero in them. So it has something to do with trying to print a zero. That should be your clue.

Answer (score 2):

> All my variables in this program were reserved and **not pre-initiated**.

You said it: The only setup you do for the *multiplier* variable is `mov [multiplier], byte 1`. This will define 1 byte, but your program then uses `mov eax, [multiplier]` that will load 4 bytes. There's no absolute guarantee that the high 3 bytes would be zero.

There's also no reason to reserve 256 bytes per variable! All of your calculations involve processing dword values, so logically you would define your variables as dwords.

You seem to have devised **an extremely convoluted way of printing a number**, involving lots of multiplications and divisions!
For the *digit_num* procedure, your comment mentions "know the digits count of the answer", but I don't see you actually *counting digits*. All you do is establishing an elevated value for the *multiplier* variable. For some inputs it will work, for some other inputs it won't...

Instead of first reversing the number and then printing the reversed version, you should temporarily store the digits in a buffer (starting from the rear of the buffer) and then printing the buffer in one go. A dword value can at most have 10 digits, so a 10-byte buffer will do:

```
section .text
_start:
    ; square of number
    mov  eax, 31                ; {2, 10, 20, 30, 31, 32, 65}
    imul eax, eax
    mov  [number], eax

    ; convert into ASCII digits and print
    call print_answer

    ; exit
    xor  ebx, ebx
    mov  eax, 1
    int  80h
; ---------------------------
print_answer:
    mov  ecx, answer + 10    ; Address above the 10-byte buffer
    mov  ebx, 10             ; CONST
    mov  eax, [number]
.more:
    xor  edx, edx            ; Dividing EDX:EAX by 10
    div  ebx
    dec  ecx                 ; Go to next lower address
    add  edx, '0'            ; Convert remainder (EDX) to ASCII
    mov  [ecx], dl           ;  and store at next lower address
    test eax, eax            ; Test quotient (EAX)
    jnz  .more               ; More to do

    ; print
    mov  edx, answer + 10    ; Address above the 10-byte buffer
    sub  edx, ecx            ;  minus address of the 1st digit gives NumberOfDigits
    mov  ebx, 1
    mov  eax, 4
    int  80h
    ret
; ---------------------------
section .bss
    number resd 1
    answer resb 10
```

Comment: *There's no absolute guarantee that the high 3 bytes would be zero.* - Not on its own, but the space is reserved in `.bss`, which is guaranteed to be zero-initialized under mainstream OSes like Linux.  So x86 being little-endian, `mov [multiplier], byte 1` + `mov eax, [multiplier]` is a correct but really inefficient way to do `mov eax,1`, involving a store-forwarding stall.  (But if you take the OP literally, they did say uninitialized, so the facts they've stated are insufficient to support the correctness of that initialization.)

Comment: Personally, I never assume anything about memory I've never written to, but it could be just a habit I've picked up from working on classic game consoles (which often relied on uninitialized RAM/register states for hardware detection or RNG seeding)

Comment: @puppydrum64: Compilers like GCC and Clang implement `static int x = 0;` as space in the BSS when targeting OSes like Linux and Windows. https://godbolt.org/z/xbjsjvPG4 (note the `.comm   symbol_name,4,4`  or `.bss` / `.space  4`) You can 100% rely on this in user-space processes under mainstream OSes.  A freestanding program often needs to zero its BSS space as part of initialization before transferring control to a C `main`, or be loaded by a bootloader that does that for it.

Comment: @puppydrum64: It's normal for a program read memory it hasn't written, such as string literals, or the machine code itself.  Or `argc` and `argv` from the stack, pointed-to by the stack pointer on process entry.  The ELF metadata that specifies which parts of the file to map into the process's address-space can also specify (with well-defined zeroing semantics) some extra memory space past the end of the file-size for a mapping, so there are bytes in the executable that requested that space be zeroed (by the OS).  If you tried to write or read some arbitrary page, your program would fault.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking there's a misunderstanding here with how variables in assembly work.

```
section .bss
    ans resb 256
    digit resb 256
    left_num resb 256
    digit_count_left_num resb 256
    rev_ans resb 256
    multiplier resb 256
```

You might think that this is the equivalent of the following C code:

```
char ans[256];
char digit[256];
char left_num[256];
char digit_count_left_num[256];
char rev_ans[256];
char multiplier[256];
```

And it is... sort of. Unlike C, assembly has *no type safety whatsoever*. Any time you access memory in assembly you're typecasting it to the register size you specify in your instruction. So taking your question literally, "what is limiting the size of variables/registers in assembly", your registers "limit" the size of your variables. (Air quotes because you can use multiple registers to make up for the lack of hardware support for 64-bit integers on 32-bit hardware.)

The important takeaway here is that **the CPU has no clue what type your data is intended to be.** C and other such languages are just very good at creating the illusion that the CPU is aware of what your data structures actually are. The labels `ans`, `digit`, etc. are just for your convenience. They represent a memory address in the `.bss` section of your program. For example, if your `.bss` section happened to be located at address `0x40000000`, the following assembly code

```
    mov [rev_ans], byte 0
    mov [multiplier], byte 1
```

gets translated by the assembler into

```
    mov [0x40000400], byte 0
    mov [0x40000500], byte 1
```

Now if you were to do a hexdump of your RAM at this point, this is what you would see:

```
0x40000500: 01 (This is the byte 1 you wrote to multiplier)
0x40000501: 00 (Linux wrote a 0 here for you but you didn't initialize this value)
0x40000502: 00 (Linux wrote a 0 here for you but you didn't initialize this value)
0x40000503: 00 (Linux wrote a 0 here for you but you didn't initialize this value)
etc.
```

From what it seems, you're *intending* the data to be an array of 8-bit bytes, I'm guessing this based on how you defined it. **But the CPU has no knowledge of this at runtime!** By using `mov eax,[multiplier]`, you're telling the CPU that your intended data type is 32-bit. Here's what's happening (and I wish that I could change text color to illustrate this better):

```
0x40000500: 01 (This is loaded into the lowest 8 bits of EAX, aka AL)
0x40000501: 00 (This is loaded into lower middle 8 bits of EAX, aka AH)
0x40000502: 00 (This is loaded into the upper middle 8 bits of EAX)
0x40000503: 00 (This is loaded into the highest 8 bits of EAX)
```

If you had values other than zero in those memory slots, you can imagine that you'd get a weird number in `eax`.

Long story short, if your goal is to read 8 bits at a time, use `mov al, [memory]` or `mov ah, [memory]` rather than `mov eax, [memory]`.