# How can i convert an integer into a string in x86-32 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to make a program in x86-32 bit assembly that take an input of string consists of 3 integers, i.e, 30 40 2. Then convert it to an integer, place it to separate registers. Lastly, make an output in form of a string with the format, "number 1: (num1), number 2: (num2), number 3: (num3)."

Here's my code:

```
section .data
    num db '0'  ; Initialize for number with value 0 of ASCII
    res db 0    ; decalre a byte res with value 0
    numStrSize equ 12

section .bss
   input resb 30    ; Reserves a buffer input of 10 bytes for user input.
    num1 resd 1
    num2 resd 1
    opCode resd 1
    str_buffer resb numStrSize

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Read input from user
    mov eax, 3     ; Sets up a sys_read system call (system call number 3).
    mov ebx, 0     ; Specifies file descriptor 0 (standard input).
    mov ecx, input ; Points ecx to the input buffer.
    mov edx, 10    ; Increase to match buffer size
    int 80h        ; Executes the system call (reads user input into input buffer).

   ; Convert string to integer
    mov esi, input      ; ESI points to the start of input
    call convertToInt
    mov [num1], eax

    call NextInt
    call convertToInt
    mov [num2], eax

    call NextInt
    call convertToInt
    mov [opCode], eax

    mov eax, [num1]
    mov ecx, str_buffer
    call IntegerToString
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, str_buffer
    mov edx, numStrSize
    int 80h

    mov eax, [num2]
    mov ecx, str_buffer
    call IntegerToString
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, str_buffer
    mov edx, numStrSize
    int 80h

    mov eax, [opCode]
    mov ecx, str_buffer
    call IntegerToString
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, str_buffer
    mov edx, numStrSize
    int 80h

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h

convertToInt:
    xor eax, eax        ; Clear EAX for storing result
    .Loop:
        movzx ebx, byte [esi]  ; Move one byte of input into EBX
        test ebx, ebx          ; Test if byte is null terminator (end of string)
        jz .end
        cmp ebx, ' '             ; Check if the character is a whitespace
        je .end      ; If whitespace, jump to skip_character
        sub ebx, '0'           ; Convert ASCII to integer (subtract ASCII value of '0')
        imul eax, eax, 10      ; Multiply current result by 10 (shift left by one decimal place)
        add eax, ebx           ; Add new digit to result
        inc esi
        jmp .Loop
    .end:
        ret

IntegerToString:
    mov ebx, 10              ; Set divisor to 10
    mov edi, ecx             ; Set EDI to point to the start of the buffer
    mov byte [edi], 0        ; Null-terminate the string

    .convert:
        add edi, numStrSize - 1  ; Move EDI to the end of the buffer
    .convert_loop:
        dec edi              ; Move back one byte in the buffer
        xor edx, edx         ; Clear EDX for division
        div ebx              ; Divide EAX by 10, result in EAX, remainder in EDX
        add dl, '0'          ; Convert remainder to ASCII character
        mov [edi], dl        ; Store ASCII character in buffer
        test eax, eax        ; Check if EAX is zero
        jnz .convert_loop    ; If not zero, continue loop

    .reverse:
        mov esi, ecx
        dec edi                  ; Decrement EDI to exclude null terminator
        jmp .start_reverse
    .start_reverse:
        .reverse_loop:
            cmp esi, edi         ; Check if pointers have crossed
            jge .done            ; If so, the string is reversed
            mov al, [esi]        ; Swap the characters
            mov bl, [edi]
            mov [esi], bl
            mov [edi], al
            inc esi              ; Move to next characters
            dec edi
            jmp .reverse_loop
        .done:
            ret


NextInt:
    .loop:
        movzx ebx, byte [esi]
        test ebx, ebx
        jz .end
        cmp ebx, ' '
        je .skipSpace
        inc esi
        jmp .loop
    .skipSpace:
        inc esi
        jmp .end
    .end:
        ret
```

I've tried to print the 3 integers I've saved. I.e my input is 100 999 1, but the output I got is:

```
100 999 99 1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the difference between what you *want* this code to do and what it *actually* does, and what is stopping you from trying to fix it?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ - that's not a sufficient problem description, see that guide to improving questions.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I want this code to give an output in string format: "number 1: (int1), number 2: (int2), number 3: (int3)." int1,2,3 is the interger from the input string. So i've tried to print the 3 intergers i've saved. I.e my input is 100 999 1, but the output i got is 100 999 99 1. i dont know why. what stopping me is i've tried to find the problem but i just cant find it. Sorry for my broken english. im not a native speaker of english

Comment: Are you saying every instruction does exactly what you want it to, yet the output is wrong?  Or are you saying you haven't used a debugger to see what each instruction does?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah every instruction does what i wanted to but somehow the output is still wrong, i use online compiler, onecompiler.com to compile my code

Comment: I have added the current output to the question. Matt, is sounds like you need to debug the code next (per Scott's advice). Does onecompiler.com offer this as a feature?

Comment: If there's no online IDE that lets you single-step your code and look at registers/memory, you'll need to install something locally.  A debugger is an essential tool for assembly language; see the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info .   I think https://onlinegdb.com/ only has GNU assembler, not NASM.

Comment: I get different output when I run this at onecompiler.com: `         100        999 4294967268`

Comment: @ScottHunter i just try it again, my input is 100 999 1, and i got 100 999 99 1

Comment: re: the title question: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) shows a good algorithm, and x86-64 asm that's easy to change to 32-bit.  [Add 2 numbers and print the result using Assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524951) is a 32-bit version that's the same idea, with an `int 0x80` write system call.

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a reversal code in *IntegerToString* ?
**The conversion already stores the decimal characters in the correct order**.

This is what your 12-byte *str_buffer* looks like:

```
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

> ```
> mov edi, ecx      ; Set EDI to point to the start of the buffer
> mov byte [edi], 0 ; Null-terminate the string
> ```

```
0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
^
EDI
```

> ```
>   add edi, numStrSize - 1  ; Move EDI to the end of the buffer
> ```

```
0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
                                 ^
                                 EDI
```

> ```
> .convert_loop:
>   dec edi              ; Move back one byte in the buffer
>   add dl, '0'          ; Convert remainder to ASCII character
>   mov [edi], dl        ; Store ASCII character in buffer
> ```

```
0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '0', ?
                               ^
                               EDI
```

> ```
> .convert_loop:
>   dec edi              ; Move back one byte in the buffer
>   add dl, '0'          ; Convert remainder to ASCII character
>   mov [edi], dl        ; Store ASCII character in buffer
> ```

```
0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', ?
                            ^
                            EDI
```

> ```
> .convert_loop:
>   dec edi              ; Move back one byte in the buffer
>   add dl, '0'          ; Convert remainder to ASCII character
>   mov [edi], dl        ; Store ASCII character in buffer
> ```

```
0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '1', '0', '0', ?
                         ^
                         EDI
```

The only post-processing that you could do is move the characters down in the buffer so that the address from which you'll print remains the same each time. But it would be better to just leave the characters where they are and return with ECX set to the address in EDI and with EDX holding the actual length which is 3 in the case of *num1* = 100.

Comment: Yeah my bad i think i should have look closely, using gbd sure is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

So i finally managed to get the output i want. Thanks for those helping me. Here is the corrected code.

```
.text
   global _start

_start:
    ; Read input from user
    mov eax, 3     ; Sets up a sys_read system call (system call number 3).
    mov ebx, 0     ; Specifies file descriptor 0 (standard input).
    mov ecx, input ; Points ecx to the input buffer.
    mov edx, 30    ; Increase to match buffer size
    int 80h        ; Executes the system call (reads user input into input buffer).
    ; Convert string to integer
    mov esi, input      ; ESI points to the start of input
    call convertToInt
    mov [num1], eax

    call NextInt
    call convertToInt
    mov [num2], eax

    call NextInt
    call convertToInt
    mov [opCode], eax

    mov eax, [num1]
    mov esi, str_buffer
    call IntegerToString
    mov ecx,eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, numStrSize
    int 80h

    mov eax, [num2]
    mov esi, str_buffer
    call IntegerToString
    mov ecx,eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, numStrSize
    int 80h

    mov eax, [opCode]
    mov esi, str_buffer
    call IntegerToString
    mov ecx,eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, numStrSize
    int 80h

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h

convertToInt:
    xor eax, eax        ; Clear EAX for storing result
    .Loop:
        movzx ebx, byte [esi]  ; Move one byte of input into EBX
        test ebx, ebx          ; Test if byte is null terminator (end of string)
        jz .end
        cmp ebx, ' '             ; Check if the character is a whitespace
        je .end      ; If whitespace, jump to skip_character
        sub ebx, '0'           ; Convert ASCII to integer (subtract ASCII value of '0')
        imul eax, eax, 10      ; Multiply current result by 10 (shift left by one decimal place)
        add eax, ebx           ; Add new digit to result
        inc esi
        jmp .Loop
    .end:
        ret

IntegerToString:
    add esi, 9
    mov byte [esi], 0  ; String terminator
    mov ebx, 10
    .next_digit:
        xor edx, edx        ; Clear edx prior to dividing edx:eax by ebx
        div ebx             ; eax /= 10
        add dl, '0'         ; Convert the remainder to ASCII 
        dec esi            ; store characters in reverse order
        mov [esi], dl
        test eax, eax            
        jnz .next_digit    ; Repeat until eax==0
        ; return a pointer to the first digit (not necessarily the start of the provided buffer)
        mov eax, esi
        ret

NextInt:
    .loop:
        movzx ebx, byte [esi]
        test ebx, ebx
        jz .end
        cmp ebx, ' '
        je .skipSpace
        inc esi
        jmp .end
    .skipSpace:
        inc esi
        jmp .end
    .end:
        ret 

section .bss
    input resb 30
    numStrSize equ 10
    num1 resd 1
    num2 resd 1
    opCode resd 1
    str_buffer resb numStrSize
```

Comment: In *NextInt* you have replaced the `jmp .loop` by another `jmp .end`. In doing so, you have effectively turned this procedure into one glorified `inc esi`  instruction. It will work with your one-space-separated test data, but why have a 14-line procedure if a mere `inc` is enough?

Comment: @SepRoland Oh wait, so i can just delete the NextInt call and replace it with inc esi and it will move esi foward once? it is the same thing like calling NextInt?