# Nasm x86-32 : writing bytes to a string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The subroutine `int_to_string` works well when writing to a 10 bytes memory buffer [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671937/nasm-x86-32-int-to-string), but outputs a weird result after I modified it to write to a string. 
Only the digit for the unit is correct (`1`). 
What is the issue here?

```
; sum of array elements (integers)
; and write to console

section .text

global _start

_start:
      mov eax, 0        
      mov ebx, array          
      mov ecx, lena
loop:
      cmp ecx, 0    
      je print  
      add eax, [ebx]
      add ebx, 4    
      sub ecx, 1
      jmp loop
print:
      ; convert integer to string
      mov  esi, msg
      call int_to_string
      
      ; call write syscall
      mov edx, lenmsg      ; length of the string
      mov ecx, msg         ; address of the string
      mov ebx, 1           ; file descriptor, in this case stdout
      mov eax, 4           ; syscall number for write
      int 0x80

      ; call exit syscall
      mov eax, 1
      int 0x80

; Input:
; eax = integer value to convert
; esi = pointer to string to store the digit characters
int_to_string:
      add esi, lenmsg-2
      mov ebx, 10               
.next_digit:
      xor edx, edx       ; clear edx prior to dividing edx:eax by ebx
      div ebx            ; eax /= 10
      add dl, '0'        ; convert the remainder to ASCII 
      dec esi            ; store characters in reverse order
      mov [esi], dl      ;
      test eax, eax           
      jnz .next_digit    ; repeat until eax==0
      ret

section .data
      array dd 10, 20, 30, 40, 501
      lena: equ $-array      ; length of array
      msg db "The sum is            .", 0xA
      lenmsg: equ $-msg      ; length of msg
```

Comment: A more efficient loop only uses the one condition at the bottom: `mov ecx, lena` `jecxz print` `loop:` `add eax, [ebx]` `add ebx, 4` `sub ecx, 4` `jnz loop` `print:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `loop` decrements ecx by 1 each time, so ecx should be initialized with a count of elements.  But you initialize it with `lena`, which is a count of bytes, i.e. 4 times too large.  So you add a whole bunch of extra garbage to your sum.

One fix would be to replace `mov ecx, lena` with `mov ecx, lena / 4`.

Comment: @macxpat: Or `lena: equ ($-array)/4`.  Or just use the pointer as a loop condition instead of a separate counter, so you only need `add ebx, 4` as loop overhead, not also a `sub` or `dec`, especially if you're not `jnz` on FLAGS set by `sub`.  (See also [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926))